# TypeScript: Using UnionToIntersection helper but preserving a subexpression

Tags: typescript

This code is simplified from a CSV writing library:

(I'm using the `UnionToIntersection` helper from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/163832)

```js
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

type Spec = 'string' | 'timestamp' | ['nullable', Spec];

type SpecToValue<T> = UnionToIntersection<
    T extends 'string' ? string :
    T extends 'timestamp' ? Date :
    T extends ['nullable', infer InnerT] ? SpecToValue<InnerT> | null :
    never
>;

declare function writeValue<T extends Spec>(spec: T, value: SpecToValue<T>): void;

function test(s1: 'string', s2: 'string' | 'timestamp', s3: ['nullable', 'string']) {
    writeValue(s1, 'hello');
    writeValue(s1, false); // error (good)
    writeValue(s1, null);  // error (good)

    writeValue(s2, 'hello'); // error (good)
    writeValue(s2, false);   // error (good)
    writeValue(s2, null);    // error (good)

    // Problem: SpecToValue<['nullable', 'string']> resolves to `never` instead of `string | null`.
    writeValue(s3, 'hello'); // ERROR (bad; I want this to be allowed)
    writeValue(s3, false);   // error (good)
    writeValue(s3, null);    // ERROR (bad; I want this to be allowed)
```

I think the problem is that the `UnionToIntersection` also converts the `SpecToValue<InnerT> | null` to an intersection, but I don't want to do that. I want to keep that as a union.

Is there a way to do that?

**Edit:** In my actual code, I have the "simple" types separated from the "nullable" types; not sure if that makes much of a difference to the solution:

```js
type SimpleSpec = 'string' | 'timestamp';
type Spec = SimpleSpec | ['nullable', SimpleSpec];

type SimpleSpecToValue<T> =
    T extends 'string' ? string :
    T extends 'timestamp' ? Date :
    never;
type SpecToValue<T> =
    T extends SimpleSpec ? SimpleSpecToValue<T> :
    T extends ['nullable', infer InnerT] ? (SpecToValue<InnerT> | null) : null
```

(Not a deal-breaker if I have to combine the definitions, though.)

Comment: I think [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w21KjW) might be what you're looking for.  If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah that looks good! In my actual code, the `Spec` and `SpecToValue` is actually split out into two levels: simple vs nullable. I added that to my question just in case it changes the answer.

Comment: [It doesn't affect the answer](https://tsplay.dev/WGG6VW) so I won't worry about it

Comment: @jcalz: It seems to affect the answer a tiny bit for this input: `ContravariantSpecToValue<['nullable', 'string'] | ['nullable', 'timestamp']>`. With your 1-layer solution, I get what I expect: `(string & Date) | null`. With your 2-layer solution, I get: `string & Date`. (This doesn't matter _that_ much for my current use case, but it would be nice to clean up this edge case.)

Comment: Surely though that's because [your version doesn't work even without `ContravariantSpecToValue`](https://tsplay.dev/wQLejW)... Are you expecting me to clean up that?  That seems to have little to do with the question, but I could look into it if it's a sticking point.

Comment: Ah yup, my original 2-layer definition wasn't equivalent to my 1-layer definition. I missed an `| null` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to apply `UnionToIntersection<T>` to the results of `SpecToValue`, because that's not the level at which you are trying to convert [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) to [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).  Instead you really want to compute `SpecToValue<T>` for each union member of `T`, and then produce the intersection of the *result*.

Essentially that means you want to apply `SpecToValue<T>` *inside* your `UnionToIntersection`-like utility type, and not vice versa:

```
type SpecToValue<T> =
  T extends 'string' ? string :
  T extends 'timestamp' ? Date :
  T extends ['nullable', infer InnerT] ? SpecToValue<InnerT> | null :
  never

type ContravariantSpecToValue<T> =
  (T extends any ? ((x: SpecToValue<T>) => void) : never) extends
  ((x: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
```

Let's test it:

```
type Combination = ContravariantSpecToValue<
  ['nullable', ['nullable', 'timestamp']] | 'timestamp'
>;
//type Combination = Date
```

Looks good, the result is `Date & (Date | null)` (or `Date`) and not `Date & Date * null` (or `never`).  And just to be sure it works with your examples:

```
declare function writeValue<T extends Spec>(
  spec: T, value: ContravariantSpecToValue<T>): void;

function test(s1: 'string', s2: 'string' | 'timestamp', s3: ['nullable', 'string']) {
  writeValue(s1, 'hello'); // okay
  writeValue(s1, false); // error
  writeValue(s1, null);  // error

  writeValue(s2, 'hello'); // error
  writeValue(s2, false);   // error
  writeValue(s2, null);    // error

  writeValue(s3, 'hello'); // okay 
  writeValue(s3, false);   // error 
  writeValue(s3, null);    // error
}
```

Also good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGUC8UDkBnYAnAlgOwHNUoAfNYHAWwkwENKxiyBtVPAVwBtPaAjTiKgA0sBAF0A3ACgpoSKIjwAKgHsAarU7sIAHiUA+ZFKhQlUCAA9gEPABN0aTLkLEA-FCf4CUAFzHT5lY29uRUNMD0jFDuACK01r7+ZpbWdg6sHNx8AsJQ+ABmEFhQAJJ4eEVKYtEKyuqa2jplFVgGpFCZnIkmFQBuRTJy0ADCKnjYtL20uLTjcIqqGlq6bUj+ABTJQWlQsyA16+sWPrWLDSv6AJTIhr0qOLbXJ31F1ynB6BtHJwVFpddIW73R41Eq+DoQfpYaSycAjFSUXj4eI4MbIKCjcZYSbTHCzYDzOpLRr+DJcHj8QQiMlZSm5VAUah0BioMTVMgMsLMxhSfTSAD0-KGGIRSLwKLRKDi1hktkUPCw0Hy7Dw8AoaIA7rhrMSVoFUiFCfp1v50AgTkoRFNlidMRMpjM5ggzss9FcTncHjDlar1XgoNZMOt0ABGE4YbBeXLoABM4c8LnanKZERZInQAGYTjSKTkRBHnEQxNcAN7+LU4HXnYMh-MACwg3BUqEuEiggqgKgA1rQQOXtRBdTWRPlNOgIK32-zzFgsCosP3K4Pq6GRJ1J1OZ3OF4uq8tgzH643OM3Jx2itvd8v97GR2OJ22TOfZ-Or0Pbx1yRun9OL6+3yuGZHk2LZth23a9lAAE3kBUCjpw47fs+25QSYFZ7towaweuj4-lur4AL4yFIQA)